# Overwrite css style with GTM before page loads

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a section of my website that has a map inside a div that has an id with "display:none;" for mobile users. I would like to use Google Tag Manager and display that div with the map but I noticed that using a trigger by pageview is kinda slow when loading. The page loads and the div eventually displays the map but it shows broken since the js already loaded.

Is there a faster way to trigger a custom html tag with GTM other than pageview? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything in GTM before page load, since GTM itself needs to be downloaded and executed first (and due to async loading you cannot exactly tell when a tag is being executed). So no, there is now way.

Comment: when loading GTM on a page there are 3 events fired - Page View, DOM Ready and Window Loaded (in this order). You cannot do anything before "Page View" event and not "page load" as you describe. Link: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679319?hl=en

Comment: You can delay the whole dom load by a second or so (1000ms). That should be enough for GTM to load, and then you can manipulate the CSS through it. But that code which would need to delay the page needs to go straight in the code (and not in the GTM), which then defies the purpose, right?

In any case, you need to intervene in the backend, in the code directly. So, why not then make the actual change to the CSS required on mobile devices, instead of running it through the GTM...